# What might be a suitable clustering algorithm to split different parts in dense optical flow?

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision, clustering

I want to split the main part(like people) in optical flow from the background, but I don't konw how to start.

I think one way is to use some kind of clustering algorithm, first split the optical flow image into small patches, define the distance function and use clustering algorithm to aggregate them. But I don't know how to define a suitble distance and find a suitable algorithm.

The other way is to use threshold, first compute the global average optical flow direction, then at each patch, compute local average direction, if local value is close to global value, then consider it as background. But this might not work when the foreground take the most place (like the bottom right image).

**One of my observation is that usually the background optical flow is usually smooth and nearly the same direction.**

[image: Image from paper : RAFT: Recurrent All-Pairs Field Transforms for Optical Flow]

---

The input to the algorithm is the predicted dense optical flow (right), which is a tensor with shape (img_height(1024), img_width(768), UV(2)), the last dimension is a 2d vector indicating the moving direction of the the pixel on the RGB photo taken by camera (left).

[image]

The original dense optical flow using arrow to visualize may look like this:
[image]

To better visualize the dense optical flow, the left image maps the vector using euclidean distance to psedu color.

The ideal ouput I want is something like the photo below. patches might belong to the foreground is clustered.

[image]